# How do you substitute a string from within a macro in GAS?

Tags: macros, substitution, gnu-assembler

I have a macro which exposes global variables to the linker from a source file compiled by GAS.

```
.macro      GLO NAME
.global     foo_\NAME
            foo_\NAME:
.endm
```

If i write...

```
GLO         var
.word       0x1234
```

... it expands to:

```
.global     foo_var
            foo_var:
.word       0x1234
```

... then i can reference those variables elsewhere:

```
extern "C" uint16_t foo_var;
```

I am vexed, that i can't seem to substitute "foo" with a string defined elsewhere.
For example,

```
.equ        SOURCE, bar
.macro      GLO NAME
.global     SOURCE\NAME
            SOURCE\NAME:
.endm
```

I have tried .equ, .set, and .macro:

```
.equ        SOURCE, bar
.set        SOURCE, bar
.macro      SOURCE
            bar
.endm
```

- None of which are substituting the string.
  How can i achieve this?